# i am trying to implement the simple linear regression using gradient decent but after implementing my value of cost function is incresing

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient-descent

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=pd.read_csv('Advertising.csv')

data=data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'] ,axis=1)
x=data.iloc[:,0].values
y=data.iloc[:,-1].values

m=0
c=0
n=len(y)
learning_rate=0.001
etration=1000
```

#created a hypothesis function here to predict thee value
def hypothesis(x,m,c):
y_pred=m*x+c
return y_pred

```
#cost function 

def cost_function(y,n,m,c):
    error = y-hypothesis(x,m,c)
    sq_error=(error)**2
    sum_sq_error=sum(sq_error)
    cost=1/(2*n)*sum_sq_error
    return cost
# gradiant decent function taking derivative

def gradient_function(m,c,n,learning_rate,etration):
    updated_c = c
    updated_m = m
    for i in range(etration):
        D_c = (-2/n)*sum((hypothesis(x,updated_m,updated_c))-y)
        D_m = (-2/n)*sum((hypothesis(x,updated_m,updated_c)-y)*x)
        updated_c= updated_c-learning_rate*D_c
        updated_m =updated_m-learning_rate*D_m
        print('cost function',cost_function(y,n,updated_m,updated_c))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gradient_function(m,c,n,learning_rate,1000)
```

after running the function my cost function shoot to infinity

Comment: Can you explain what "shoot to infinity" means?

Comment: values of cost function showing infinity